# Is there any overhead with referencing static functions as part of a class definition?

Tags: c++

I am currently implementing some utility functions for implementing some libraries I am working on. I was forced to choose between segmenting the functions as static members as part of a class definition within a more general namespace, or enter more specific namespace and then define the functions. I choose the former feeling as it was more flexible in the way those utility classes may be drawn into scope (using or inheritance) though I was unsure whether there was any overhead associated with this design choice or not:

Is

```
namespace Utilities {
  struct CharUtil {
    static void foo();
  }
}
Utilities::CharUtil::foo();
```

slower than

```
namespace Utilities {
  namespace CharUtil {
    void foo();
  }
}
Utilities::CharUtil::foo();
```

?

Is the former faster using inheritance?

Comment: There is only one way to know if it is faster: by measuring it. And even then, *faster* is not relevant. Only *fast enough* matters.

Comment: Sure enough, I'm splitting hairs here. I am trying to develop good habits!

Comment: @IanHaggerty Nice question, but be prepared to get "premature optimization"-cries at you from all around StackOverflow. But once you realize that a member function is just a free function with an additional parameter and a static member function is just a free function, the question becomes obsolete anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference at all between the two cases, except for functions' mangled names. Static functions do not have `this` pointer as hidden argument. The compiler generated code for both functions will be the same.